# missing ESSID from aircrack-ng

Tags: macos, wpa2, aircrack-ng

I'm using Mac OS X and I was able to sniff packet from my homeNetwork (in order to learn more about how things goes on).

I'm sending a deauth command to all my devices to disconnect them and then start sniffing. I've captured a handshake and I can tell that it's valid by testing it against aircrack-ng like on the image bellow.

But the problem is the missing ESSID that couldn't be verified even after using the suggested `-e` option.

Does anyone have an idea how to solve this?

[image]

This is the [handshake .cap file](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=98533321905208524220) if someone wanted to take a look at it. The ESSID is `ooredooF00F62`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just realized (with more research) that aircrack-ng needs a management frame containing the ESSID (it can be `beacon/probe response/reassociation request`) and two data frames containing the EAPOL messages.
so i just captured a beacon frame from the AP and then used the wireshark's `mergecap` tool to merge the 2 .cap files (beacon.cap and eapol.cap) and that worked perfectly!